# Filter GridView using a textbox with commas C#

Tags: c#, gridview, filter

I'm trying to filter trough by gridview using a textbox when I need to use commas to search for specific items in that grid view

This is my gridview:

[image]

As you can see the column `Ingredientes` contains items separated by commas. What I'm trying to do is if I write in the `Ingredientes` textbox "repolho,salsa" for example the row appears.

At the moment I can search if the `Ingredientes` column has just a single item like that one with the "ing"

This is my code

```
// Procura pelos ingredientes
else if (txtTitulo.Text == "" && txtIngredientes.Text != "")
{
    dataGridReceitas.Rows.Clear();

    if (File.Exists(receitas))
    {
        sr = File.OpenText(receitas);
        string linha = "";
        int x = 0;

        while((linha = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] campos = linha.Split(';');

            if(txtIngredientes.Text == campos[3])
            {
                dataGridReceitas.Rows.Add(1);
                dataGridReceitas[0, x].Value = campos[0];
                dataGridReceitas[1, x].Value = campos[1];
                dataGridReceitas[2, x].Value = campos[2];
                dataGridReceitas[3, x].Value = campos[3];

                x++;
            }
        }

        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this :

```
else if (txtTitulo.Text == "" && txtIngredientes.Text != "")
{
    string searchValue = txtIngredientes.Text;
    dataGridReceitas.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
    try
    {
        bool valueResult = false;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridReceitas.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Cells[3].Value != null && row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Equals(searchValue))
            {
                int rowIndex = row.Index;
                dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Selected = true;
                valueResult = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!valueResult)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to find " + searchtextBox.Text, "Not Found");
            return;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: its does select the row that i searched for but just selects i need that all the rows dissapear and the oonly one left being the one i searched for